# Возможен ли PIVOT над CLOB данными?

Tags: sql, oracle

Рассмотрим пример запроса:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t2.col_1
             , t2.col_2
             , t2.col_clob
          FROM table_1 t2
          LEFT JOIN table_2 t1 ON t1.col_1 = t2.col_1
         WHERE t1.col_2 = 'some_value'
           AND t2.col_2 IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')) xx
 PIVOT ( max(to_char(col_clob))
          FOR col_2 IN ('val1' AS val1
                      , 'val2' AS val2
                      , 'val3' AS val3 ));
```

В этом запросе table_2.col_clob имеет тип данных CLOB. Очевидно, нам нужна какая-то агрегирующая функция для PIVOT. Предполагается, что значения уникальны, поэтому возьму max. Агрегирующая функция не будет работать с CLOB, поэтому нужна to_char() функция. И заданная конструкция прекрасно работает до тех пор, пока to_char может отрабатывать без ошибки, выдавая на выходе таблицу:

```
|  col_1  |  val1  |  val2  |  val3  |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|
|   ...   |   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |
```

Но я столкнулся с ситуацией, когда col_clob длиннее 4000 символов, поэтому так просто не перевести его в varchar2. Как можно обойти ситуацию? Чтобы иметь на выходе такую же таблицу, но в этот раз столбцы val1, val2, val3 были бы именно CLOB столбцами, а не varchar2?

Также отмечу, что другой подход с поворотом:

```
SELECT col_1
     , max(val1) AS val1
     , max(val2) AS val2
     , max(val3) AS val3
  FROM (SELECT t1.col_1
             , CASE
                 WHEN t1.col_2 = 'val1' THEN col_clob
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS val1
             , CASE
                 WHEN t1.col_2 = 'val2' THEN col_clob
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS val2
             , CASE
                 WHEN t1.col_2 = 'val3' THEN col_clob
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS val3
          FROM table_1 t1
          LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.col_1 = t1.col_1
         WHERE t2.ppcd = 'some_value'
           AND t1.col_2 IN
               ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
 GROUP BY col_1;
```

Также не работает из-за необходимости агрегации, а как я упоминал выше - max() не работает с CLOB, поэтому мы попадаем в ту же ситуацию.

Comment: Вообще говоря, вопрос ощущается достаточно горячим. Но почему-то прокликав с десяток вопросов в англоязычном сегменте стековерфлоу с похожими ключевыми словами, я так и не увидел решения =\

Comment: а пробовал написать свою реализацию max, которая работает с клобами?

Answer (score 0):

Отмечу как возможный ответ просто потому что это работает, но это отвратительное решение, поскольку у нас тут могут быть десятки джойнов самих на себя, если рассматривается поболее трех поворачиваемых столбцов:

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT t1.col_1
       , CASE WHEN t1.col_2 = 'val1' THEN col_clob END AS val1
       , CASE WHEN t1.col_2 = 'val2' THEN col_clob END AS val2
       , CASE WHEN t1.col_2 = 'val3' THEN col_clob END AS val3
    FROM table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.col_1 = t1.col_1
   WHERE t2.ppcd = 'some_value'
     AND t1.col_2 IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
)
SELECT t_pk.*,
  t1.val1,
  t2.val2,
  t3.val3
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col_1 FROM t) t_pk
  LEFT JOIN t t1 ON t_pk.col_1 = t1.col_1 AND t1.val1 is not null
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t_pk.col_1 = t2.col_1 AND t2.val2 is not null
  LEFT JOIN t t3 ON t_pk.col_1 = t3.col_1 AND t3.val3 is not null;
```